# Looping in php to add an array key

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this array:

```
array(3) {
    [0] = > array(4) {
        [0] = > int(11)[1] = > string(14)"28/07/14 13:05" [2] = > string(8)"a" [3] = > string(15)"b"
    }[1] = > array(4) {
        [0] = > int(12)[1] = > string(14)"28/07/14 15:15" [2] = > string(7)"c" [3] = > string(6)"d"
    }[2] = > array(4) {
        [0] = > int(13)[1] = > string(14)"28/07/14 15:30" [2] = > string(8)"e" [3] = > string(8)"f"
    }
}
```

Coming from a PHP foreach statement, now.. my question is very simple: it is possible (Notice: using another for each loop) to add for each rows of the array a [4] key and a new value? In order to obtain this:

```
array(3) {
        [0] = > array(5) {
            [0] = > int(11)[1] = > string(14)"28/07/14 13:05" [2] = > string(1)"a" [3] = > string(1)"b" [4] = > string(8)"NEWVALUE"
        }[1] = > array(5) {
            [0] = > int(12)[1] = > string(14)"28/07/14 15:15" [2] = > string(1)"c" [3] = > string(1)"d" [4] = > string(8)"NEWVALUE"
        }[2] = > array(5) {
            [0] = > int(13)[1] = > string(14)"28/07/14 15:30" [2] = > string(1)"e" [3] = > string(1)"f" [4] = > string(8)"NEWVALUE"
        }
    }
```

I hope you understand, thanks in advance

**EDIT**: Probably i'm not clear.. i will post my php code:

```
...
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$expression = '(//table[@cellpadding="3"])[1]/tr[position() > 1]';
$rows = $xpath->query($expression);

$results = array();
$result = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {

  $td = $row->childNodes;

  $data = $td->item(2)->nodeValue;
  $immagine = $td->item(4)->firstChild->attributes->getNamedItem("src")->nodeValue;
  $team1 = $td->item(10)->nodeValue;
  $team2 = $td->item(14)->nodeValue;
  $unixTime = time()*1000;

  $result[0] = $unixTime;  
  $result[1] = $data;
  $result[2] = $team1;
  $result[3] = $team2;
  $results[] = $result;

  }

$expression1 = '(//table[@cellpadding="3"])[1]/tr[position() > 1]/td[19]/a[1]/@href';
$rows1 = $xpath->query($expression1);
$result = array();

foreach ($rows1 as $row) {

  $result[4] = $row->value;
  $results[] = $result;

}

var_dump($results);
```

Thanks for these answers

**EDIT:** I have put $result = array(); before foreach, but now i have this strange result: it is printed a "130" items array which consists on "65" elements that contained the 4 keys and after other "65" items in which are displayed all the 5 keys! But the first 4 keys are not looped!!

Example

for 0th to 64th element:

```
[0]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(11) [1]=> string(1) "a" [2]=> string(1) "b" [3]=> string(1) "c"
...
[64]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(74) [1]=> string(2) "a1" [2]=> string(2) "b1" [3]=> string(2) "c3"
```

for 65th to 130th element:

```
[65]=> array(5) { [0]=> int(11) [1]=> string(1) "a" [2]=> string(1) "b" [3]=> string(1) "c" [4]=> string(36) "popup.asp?tp=2100&lang=en&idm=556296" }
...
[130]=> array(5) { [0]=> int(11) [1]=> string(1) "a" [2]=> string(1) "b" [3]=> string(1) "c" [4]=> string(36) "popup.asp?tp=2100&lang=en&idm=452452" }
```

**EDIT:** Now it is displayed a 65 rows array, correctly number, but the first 4 are not looped! Example:

for 0th to 64th elements:

```
[0]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(11) [1]=> string(1) "a" [2]=> string(1) "b" [3]=> string(1) "c" [4]=> string(36) "popup.asp?tp=2100&lang=en&idm=452452"
[1]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(11) [1]=> string(1) "a" [2]=> string(1) "b" [3]=> string(1) "c" [4]=> string(36) "popup.asp?tp=2100&lang=en&idm=333352"
...
[65]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(11) [1]=> string(1) "a" [2]=> string(1) "b" [3]=> string(1) "c" [4]=> string(36) "popup.asp?tp=2100&lang=en&idm=999999"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `&` because it is only refference and it will be changed in `$array` so.

```
foreach($array as &$bit) {
  $bit[] = "New value";
}
```

The output is same variable as input `$array`.

Comment: [] is pushing a new element to an existing array so I think it doesnt even matter.

Comment: The Problem is, that you are clearing `$result` with every single Loop at both foreachs. Put `$result = array();` before foreach.

Comment: Yea you are right i've edited my code, but now i have another problem.. infact, see my question!

Comment: Why dont you define `$results = array();` before each loop and `$result = array();` at the beginning of loop?

Comment: Edit my code, now my array show correctly 65 rows, but the first 4 key are not looped!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the original `$array` in the `foreach` like this:

```
//$array our array

foreach($array as $key => $value){
 $array[$key][] = 'NEW VAL';
 //equivalent to use $value = 'NEW VAL' but it should be referenced
}
```

Comment: +1, nice working example, but using references is more efficient & nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible using the [] operator.

You can enter any key into the brackets, or if the keys are numeric like in your case: simple leave it empty to increment the numeric count by 1 and add 1 element.

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    $value[] = "NEWVALUE";
}
```